How to align grease pencil objects and mesh in a rig with bone relative?
I am finding issues pairing the grease pencil object in a rig. I have been following the instructions as per the youtube tutorial by Sophie Jantak however I have made my own model from scratch and have been working with a bird rig instead of a horse one. Following is the link to the video about animating the grease pencil:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_yOiKr_-KI&t=0s
I am attaching examples of 2 problems below:

I paired the grease pencil objects for the neck to the rig with bone relative as instructed in the video and also divided the strokes into seperate objects to be paired separate with the division in the neck for each individual bone. However while moving the rig the motion of the grease pencil and mesh never align with the grease pencil objects always trailing behind.


In the rig there isn't a seperate control for the lower leg bone and the mesh of that bone is attached to the knee and foot with IK. Hence I haven't been able to correctly parent the grease pencil object. I have been only been able to parent it to control of the foot or knee. And neither of them individually give a good result.



I tried adjusting the weight paint of the mesh to check if reducing the distortion of the mesh would help get a more accurate alignment but it's not giving a good enough of a result. Please suggest any solutions that could make this easier! Any suggestion for a different method to achieve the some result as the tutorial would be appreciated!
